ESP32-S3 Does not read BME680 Data
I build a PCB using ESP32-S3-WROOM-1-N16R2 Controller. I programmed a BME680 sensor with this MCU. My pinouts are,
BME_SCK 38
BME_MISO 19
BME_MOSI 15
BME_CS 5

This is my Arduino code,
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include "Adafruit_BME680.h"

#define BME_SCK 38
#define BME_MISO 19
#define BME_MOSI 15
#define BME_CS 5

#define SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA (1013.25)

//Adafruit_BME680 bme(&Wire); // I2C
//Adafruit_BME680 bme(&Wire1); // example of I2C on another bus
//Adafruit_BME680 bme(BME_CS); // hardware SPI
Adafruit_BME680 bme(BME_CS, BME_MOSI, BME_MISO,  BME_SCK);

void setup() {
 Serial.begin(9600);
 while (!Serial);

 SPI.begin(BME_SCK, BME_MISO, BME_MOSI, BME_CS);
 SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE0); // Set SPI mode (0, 1, 2, or 3)

 Serial.println(F("BME680 test"));

 if (!bme.begin()) {
   Serial.println("Could not find a valid BME680 sensor, check wiring!");
   while (1);
 } else {
   Serial.println("BME680 sensor initialized successfully.");
 }

 // Set up oversampling and filter initialization
 bme.setTemperatureOversampling(BME680_OS_8X);
 bme.setHumidityOversampling(BME680_OS_2X);
 bme.setPressureOversampling(BME680_OS_4X);
 bme.setIIRFilterSize(BME680_FILTER_SIZE_3);
 bme.setGasHeater(320, 150); // 320*C for 150 ms
}

void loop() {
  if (! bme.performReading()) {
   Serial.println("Failed to perform reading :(");
   return;
  }
 Serial.print("Temperature = ");
 Serial.print(bme.temperature);
 Serial.println(" *C");

 Serial.print("Pressure = ");
 Serial.print(bme.pressure / 100.0);
 Serial.println(" hPa");

 Serial.print("Humidity = ");
 Serial.print(bme.humidity);
 Serial.println(" %");

 Serial.print("Gas = ");
 Serial.print(bme.gas_resistance / 1000.0);
 Serial.println(" KOhms");

 Serial.print("Approx. Altitude = ");
 Serial.print(bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA));
 Serial.println(" m");

 Serial.println();
 delay(2000);
}

I got output like,
R~�g�BME680 test
Could not find a valid BME680 sensor, check wiring!
R~R~�g�BME680 test
Could not find a valid BME680 sensor, check wiring!
R~�g�R��g�BME680 test
Could not find a valid BME680 sensor, check wiring!

I go through the ESP32-S3 datasheet,
It says Any GPIO pins, we will assign for SPI, I2C Communications.
Datasheet link for your reference,
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3-wroom-1_wroom-1u_datasheet_en.pdf
ESP32-S3 series datasheet,
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-s3_datasheet_en.pdf
and also i wired the same pins in ESP32-S3 EVK and programmed with BME680, it gives data perfectly, I don't know what's the issue. How to solve this issue?

The pin 38 of the module is GPIO2, not GPIO38. Therefore the #define BME_SCK 38 is wrong (all the pin defines are wrong). Your code uses the wrong GPIO references. Please get familiar with the Arduino ESP32 pin definition for ESP32-S3 and also the Table 3 Pin Definitions of ESP32-S3-WROOM-1 datasheet.

Thank you @hcheung ! I was wrongly updated the GPIO Numbers. Now it perfectly gives the BME680 Outputs.

I do not see anything wrong with the code. Please check for broken traces, cold joints, short circuits, etc. Use a multimeter to check the continuity of each SPI signal pin (SCK, MISO, MOSI, and CS) between the ESP32-S3 and the sensor. Here is a design that you can see for a cross-reference.
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/IoT_Indoor_system_with_ESP32_to_monitor_Temperature_Humidity_Pressure_and_Air_a1cf31ba.html
